# What is the benefit of a 3 tier system?

Tags: equipment, brewing

I see a lot of people with the 3 tier brewing system. What is the benefit and What are the different levels for? [This system is what I am referencing.](https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/562502_10151417843083310_1001155967_n.jpg)

Comment: Keep in mind that the brewer makes the beer, not the equipment. A 3 tier system can be an advantage for one style of brewing, but it's not an overall advantage. You can make beer just as good as is produced on a 3 tier system with much simpler equipment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Top tier - Sparge Water

Middle tier - Mash Tun

Bottom Tier - Boil Kettle

The main benefit to having the vessels stacked in this manner is that you can transfer water/wort without the use of a siphon or an electric pump, everything can be gravity fed from top to bottom. Three tiers also allow you to easily fly sparge much easier than other setups (Obviously you can still batch sparge if you choose).

**Example:**

- Heat Strike water in top tier, open top valve to let it run off into your mash tun (second tier)
- Add grains, mash as you normally would
- While mashing, heat sparge water in top tier
- After mash is complete, open top valve and bottom valve to fly sparge
- Once your wort is run off you can boil in the bottom tier

Comment: Another benefit is space-saving. I have a 3-vessel system side by side with pumps, and it takes more room.